# Windows Message Pump pausing when clicking a Scrollbar control

Tags: c#, .net, windows, xna

I've set my XNA game's DeviceWindowHandle to a PictureBox with Dock set to Fill on a Form, effectively providing the powerful array of .NET controls to my game. I'm aware this comes with a handful of niggly things to clean up, one of which is my problem explained below.

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to avoid the WM pump pausing when doing things like clicking to drag a ScrollBar control, or right clicking in a TextBox control, this ultimately causes my renderSurface (the dock filled pictureBox) to stop being drawn to temporarily. Information on this seems sparse, though it's likely i'm not looking in the right places.

I could tie in some custom drawn XNA ScrollBars and set ShortcutsEnabled on the .NET TextBox's to false, but i would rather fix the root of this problem if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

XNA works by having a *game loop*.  *WinForms* and native c++ Windows GUI apps work by having a *message pump*.  Sounds like you have fused the two somehow.

Perhaps you need to call the base [Game.Update()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.game.update.aspx) somehow from within your forms's [Control.WndProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.wndproc(v=vs.110).aspx)